# I'm trying to implement two new commands but they are being ignored on my Sikuli script

Tags: python, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I'm trying to add two new lines (the last "if exists" and "doubleClick") but they are not being recognized.

This is the function I already have:

```
def do(a, b, ab, abc, ef, efg):
    if not (exists(a, 0) and exists(ab, 0)):
        return

    doubleClick(abc)
    start = time.time()

    while exists(ab, 0):
        wait(0.1)

    while time.time() < (start + 3) and exists(a, 0):
        pass

    if exists(a, 0):
        doubleClick(b)
        return

    #to be implemented, it has been ignored by the function/script. 
    #It should be triggered whenever the img5 appears. 
    #just to be clear, the img5 will only exist if the img1 doesn't exist

    if exists(ef, 0):
        doubleClick(efg)

while True:
    do(a="img1", b="img2", ab="img11", abc="img111", ef="img5", efg="img51")
    do(a="img1", b="img2", ab="img12", abc="img121", ef="img5", efg="img51")
```

I already tried to remove the return, add a new pass, put a new return, but nothing has been effective.

Everything runs smoothly except the part I'm trying to add.

It's just anything happens, the function is ignoring that part.

Thank you for all your help.

I'm sorry for any inconvenience.

I'm still learning how to code, I'm an amateur.

Comment: First, make sure it is definitely being ignored. Maybe it's just the doubleClick that is not doing its job. To check that, add some prints to your code and see what is the actual flow. Add a print before the doubleClick inside your last "if exists" function as well as inside the doubleClick().

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your attention.

I already did that and It's definitely being ignored.

Is there any other thing I can do?

Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Just keep adding printout throughout your script and see what areas it reaches.

Comment: @EugeneS

If you don't mind, can you elaborate, please?

All other commands are being perfectly executed, do you still think I should redo all the prints I already have done?

Thank you for your attention and your help.
I'm sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: All I am suggesting here is for you to debug your code, meaning go line by line and trace the **actual** flow of your script. Since real debugging is not possible in Sikuli IDE, I am suggesting to use prints to trace the flow of your code.

Comment: @EugeneS

That's fine. 

I'm sorry If my words seemed rude or something like that, I didn't mean to.

I'll redo again. Do you have any suggestion to change the code in case I get no print?

Thank you so much for your help and attention.

I'm sorry for all the inconvenience.

Comment: Your question is also on SikuliX Q&A board in launchpad:
https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/678458 Please consolidate your actions with respect to the answers you get. What is the current state?

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience. 

I posted here as well because I didn't get a response there on the first day and It was kind of urgent, I didn't mean to disrespect anybody.

I've answered in the SikuliX Q&A. 

Again, I apologize for the inconvenience. 

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RaiMan [helped me in the SikuliX Q&A](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/678458).

(Solution) How it should be:

```
def do(a, b, ab, abc, ef, efg):
    if not exists(a, 0):
        if exists(ef, 0):
            doubleClick(efg)
            return
        return
    if not exists(ab, 0):
        return
```